# How to escape special characters on batch file when setting variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

I need to set a variable with the string **!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a** inside a batch script. I'm aware that I have to escape some special characters there but I couldn't quite get it right.

My delayed variable expansion is ON, and based on https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php, I tried this:

- SET PASS=^^!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a
- SET PASS=^^!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a
- SET PASS=^^!5[4U}~YfWWre""4a
- SET "PASS=!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a"
- SET "PASS=^^!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a"
- SET "PASS=^^!5[4U}~YfWWre""4a"

None of them have worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set variables when [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is **dis**abled and enable it later if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "var=!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a"
ECHO var=%var%
SET var
GOTO :EOF
```

works perfectly well for me... but you're using `delayedexpansion` so

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET "var=^!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a"
ECHO var=%var%
SET var
GOTO :EOF
```

which shows that it depends on quite how you are displaying the string.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion
SET "var=!5[4U}~YfWWre"4a"
ECHO var=%var%
SET var
endlocal&SET "var=%var:!=^!%"
ECHO var=%var%
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

demonstrates the same phenomenon - and if the string contains multiple `!` like `!5[4U}~!YfWWre"4a` the difference between `echo` which evaluates the string and `set` which does not is even greater.

so the quick answer would be - go back to `disabledelayedexpansion` mode when using the value.

Comment: That works, but do I have to enable delayed expansion again? Or that's just enabled at runtime?

Comment: executing an `endlocal` instruction will restore the environment exactly to what it was when the previous `setlocal` was executed, including `delayedexpansion` state. It also reverts all environment variable values to their stat at that time. The `endlocal&set var=%var%`  is a parsing trick that allows a changed environment variable to be exported over the border. It *is* possible to use `setlocal` as a switch and toggle between `delayedexpansion` modes - BUT it was designed to be used in a "frame" `setlocal...endlocal` so there is a limit of 32 nested `setlocal`s that can be used in this way.